# Использование loop во view aiohttp app

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Есть aiohttp application в котором одна из view получает список из n штук доменов...
Мне их нужно все прочекать. Для этого я использую отдельный loop и возвращаю json с данными

views.py

```
async def check_domains(request):
    if request.body_exists:
        domains = await request.read()
        response = aiochecker.main(data=domains)
        return response
```

aiochecker.py

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def check_api(domain, session):
    ....

async def create_task(data):
    .....

def main(data):
    json = asyncio.run(create_task(data=data))
    return json
```

Правильно ли я делаю?...Как можно улучшить логику?

Answer (score 1):

```
response = aiochecker.main(data=domains)
```

возможно блокирует основной loop. Стоит или использовать executor оставив так или сразу запускать на рабочем loop

```
response = await aiochecker.create_task(data)
```

В чем смысл в nest_asyncio в Вашем случае?